# C# sort array of structs

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting

I am running a simulation part of which requires sort of array of pairs of values.
When I used Array.Sort(v1,v2) it sorts 2 arrays based on first and all the simulation takes roughly 9 ms. 
But I need to sort based on first then second so I created array of structs. See my code below.

```
private struct ValueWithWeight : IComparable<ValueWithWeight>
{
    public double Value;
    public double Weight;
    public int CompareTo(ValueWithWeight other)
    {
        int cmp = this.Value.CompareTo(other.Value);
        if (cmp != 0)
            return cmp;
        else
            return this.Weight.CompareTo(other.Weight);
    }
} 

void Usage() 
{
    ValueWithWeight[] data = FillData();
    Array.Sort(data);
}
```

Now it takes roughly 27ms. Is there any better way to sort ?

Comment: And a sort taking 27ms is an actual problem? Are you sure you're not micro-optimizing?

Comment: if you try to optimize your code at any cost it may make your code hard to understand for your self. dont care about 27ms or 9ms...

Comment: Create a proper benchmark. We don't know how you obtain the numbers, and because of that, the mentioned order of magnitude is meaningless. You may as well be seeing timer inaccuracy. Also is your question really _"Why does comparing two values takes roughly twice as long as comparing one value"_?

Comment: When you did `Array.Sort(v1, v2)`, were both arrays `v1` (the keys) and `v2` (the values; do they correspond to "Weight"?) of type `double[]`? You do not give much details. How did you measure the times? Was it the exact same data in both cases? It could be that sorting arrays of `double` has some run-time optimizations as compared to sorting arrays of user-defined value types that implement `IComparable<>`, but I cannot say if that is relevant from the info you provided.

Comment: There is more work to sorting first by "value" and then by "weight", so it is fair that more work takes more time. Especially if very many values are the same, it is easy enough to get the arrays sorted by the values, but sorting lexicographically on [ value , weight ] is harder.

Comment: @Itzchakov: I don't think this is micro-optimizing. The PO must be doing high frequency trading, so every nanosecond counts.

Comment: I just wrote a test that sorts an array (type `double[]`) with 10 million random `double`, and compared that to an array of user-defined `struct`, each struct having only one (non-static) field of type `double`, the struct implementing `IComparable<>`. Both arrays come from the same random values, of course. Sorting the array of user-defined struct takes about twice as long as sorting the `double[]`. Tried with Release build (optimizations), x64 build, and debugger not attached when running.

Comment: This code is called very often so the time is critical here.  I did use exact same data in both cases. There were about 2000 values and just few ~10 times where values were the same.  I do think  Jeppe Stig Nielsen is right and Array.Sort(keys,values) has some internal optimization. It just does not fit my requirement of sorting on both fields.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're going to extremely optimize it please consider following:

1. Array.Sort runs over your array and performs comparison. In your case, there will not be unboxing since you implemented an interface on structure.
2. Array.Sort performs swap of elements while sorting. Swapping is internally memmove. Your structure takes at least 16 bytes. You can try to reduce impact by allocating your double values in class. Class will always occupy IntPtr.Size bytes (because you will store pointers) so it should copy less bytes.

Comment: This might be a good idea, but no one knows for sure. Maybe you can do some experiments and report the results, like @Jeppe did?

Comment: I tried changing to class.  Timing went from 27 to 33

Comment: @SparcU will test and tell results from my side. Sounds weird.